# HTMLElement to HTMLInputCheckBox

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I have a problem when working with WebBrowser in C #.

Seeking the object "input" in this way

```
HtmlDocument sHTML = webBrowser.Document;
ObjElement HtmlElement;

ObjElement = sHTML.GetElementById (sValue);
if (objElement != null)
{
     ObjElement.SetAttribute ("value", sText);
}
```

But now I need to work with a checkbox (HtmlInputCheckBox)

```
HtmlInputCheckBox OtherObjElement;

OtherObjElement = sHTML.GetElementById (sValue); <====== ERROR :(
if (OtherObjElement != null)
{
    if (!OtherObjElement.checked) OtherObjElement.click
}
```

How I can convert a HTMLElement in HtmlInputCheckBox?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Did you try 'sHTML.GetElementById (sValue) as HtmlInputCheckBox'?

Comment: I can't :(. VS say "cant convert System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement to System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckbox by reference converting ...